# Clump and eliminate classes in a raster in ArcMap or R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, arcgis-9.3

after interpolation of sediment classes, I obtained a raster which looks like the image below (sample of the river). I would like to clump and eliminate areas within the raster that are below a certain area. I am open to use R or ArcMap 9.3.

In searching I have come across the Shrink and Expand functions in Arc. However, it doesnt work on my dataset. The function provided [on this site](http://scrogster.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/applying-a-circular-moving-window-filter-to-raster-data-in-r/) looks promising, by applying a moving filter window in the `raster` package in `r`. However it does so for a continuous variable, and mine is categorical.

Any suggestions would be welcomed, thanks.

[image]

Comment: In R you may consider a transformation matrix from categorials, i.e. A, B, etc. to integers (1, 2...). That is to overcome the restriction you mentioned. Using the same transformation/concordnace you can reverse the process

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a [sieve](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91609/where-can-i-use-a-sieve-filter) approach would work for you. This is a much more robust way to establish a MMU (minimal mapping unit) or filter data that focal approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need to achieve this using R:

```
# packages
library("raster")
library("igraph")

# load your raster
rast <- raster("your_raster.tif")
```

Now it might be straightforward to do it for all classes at the same time but I will just illustrate how to do it for class 1, you may do it individually and then unite the results as it's easy to automate:

```
# copy raster and assign "NA" to all pixels which are not class 1
rast_class_1 <- rast
rast_class_1[rast!=class_1_value]<-NA

# clumped pixels
clumpz <- clump(rast_class_1, directions=8)

# frecuency table of clumps
f <- data.frame(freq(clumpz))

# which rows of the data.frame are only represented by clumps under 8 pixels?
str(which(f$count <= 8))

# which values do these correspond to?
str(f$value[which(f$count <= 8)])

# put these into a vector of clump ID's to be removed
excludeID <- f$value[which(f$count <= 8)]

# exclude these
rast_class_1[clumpz %in% excludeID] <- NA

# write to disk
rf <- writeRaster(rast_class_1, filename="filtered_class_1.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```